# Define common files for GAE projects

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python

I have two different projects in Google app engine account. The folders structure in my computer is as following:

- parent_folder

  - common_folder
  - project1_folder
  - project2_folder

I have few python classes in common_folder that I want to use in both projects (project1 and project2).

I want to import the common classes into my projects, so Google App Engine will recognize them also on Production env (maybe GAE can create a copy of the common files when uploading?)

I tried using the following code in order to import my class from a specific parent directory path:

```
import os
PARENT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
print PARENT_DIR
def load_src(name, fpath):
    import os, imp
    return imp.load_source(name, os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), fpath))

load_src("globals", PARENT_DIR +"/common/globals.py")
from globals import *
```

This code worked only from my localhost environment but when I uploaded it to GAE, it didn't recognize the class:

```
> File
> "/base/data/home/apps/s~loan-management-system/1.394267205500555512/main.py",
> line 39, in load_src
>     return imp.load_source(name, os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), fpath)) IOError: [Errno 2] No
> such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the error you see is that nothing above the module/service dir (or app dir for single module apps) is uploaded to GAE during deployment.

You can symlink the necessary file(s) inside your app dirs, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/34291789/4495081. The deployment utility knows to follow the symlink and include the common folder package in the deployment.

I would suggest making the common folder a package (add a `__init__.py` file) then [vendor it in](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27#installing_a_library) inside each application but instead of copying/installing the code just symlink the common code dir inside the `lib` dir.

Then you don't need to fiddle with the path manually, in your app you'd just use the classes like this (assuming for example that `MyClass` comes from `common_folder/class.py`):

```
from common_folder.class import MyClass
```

Comment: It works. Thanks. I created a folder called 'models' and inside it an empty __init__.py file and all the common python files. Than I created a symlink in my projects to that folder.