# Import across modules in Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-import, google-app-engine-python

I have a Python Google App Engine project structured as follows:

```
app/
    handlers/
        register_user.py
    models/
        user.py
```

The `user.py` file contains a class `User(ndb.Model)`.

I'm trying to access the `User` class from `register_user.py` to create and put a new user in the database. Normally, I'd just import it like this:

```
from ..models.user import User
```

But this errors out because I'm trying to import something from above my root package - so I'm guessing models is my root package, and I can't get back to the `app` package?

Right now, I'm able to work around it by importing like this:

```
import importlib
User = importlib.import_module('models.user').User
```

I think this is kind of messy, though. So what's the "right" way of importing my User class?

**Edit:** The full stack trace:

```
Attempted relative import beyond toplevel package (/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py:1552)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1535, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1529, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1278, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1102, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 572, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~polly-chat/1.394430414829237783/main.py", line 48, in post
    receive_message(messaging_event)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~polly-chat/1.394430414829237783/messaging/handler.py", line 39, in receive_message
    intent_picker.respond_to_postback(messaging_event)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~polly-chat/1.394430414829237783/messaging/intent_picker.py", line 71, in respond_to_postback
    intent = importlib.import_module('intents.register_user')
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~polly-chat/1.394430414829237783/intents/register_user.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ..models import messenger_user
ValueError: Attempted relative import beyond toplevel package
```

(The package names here are different; I simplified them above to make the example more general)

Comment: Please post the **full text** of the traceback you're getting.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand but what happens if `from models.user import User`

Comment: @joelgoldstick that did the trick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Dan is on the right track, however there is no need to vendor your own code. The vendoring system is to manage third-party dependencies with pip and should be totally unnecessary for your use case, and vendoring your own code would violate the conventions.

Based on what you've told us, you should be able to import your code with just

`from models import user`

If that doesn't work, you should figure out why, but you definitely do not need the vendor extension or importlib to solve it.

Your base module is wherever your base WSGI application is located, which is going to be defined by where your `app.yaml` routes to. Typically, your `app.yaml` will contain something like:

```
- url: .*  # This regex directs all routes to main.app
  script: main.app
```

In this case, in the same directory as `app.yaml` there is a `main.py` that contains an `app` WSGI application. In some other cases, `script` might be `application.main.app`, in which case the `app` variable is in `application/main.py` and then the application directory would be the base directory.

Every Python package containing modules should contain an `__init__.py` file in its directory, as Dan mentioned. As a side note if you do use a `lib` directory for third-party code it won't contain an `__init__.py` since it's not a Python package (just a directory that contains Python packages). The fact that its not a package is why you use the vendor extension Dan described to make sure the packages it contains are on the import path.

In my experience, relative imports are rarely needed and can get you into problems like these so I would just avoid them.

If you're still stuck, lay out the entire file structure of your application, including the `app.yaml` contents, and each of the subdirectories, including whether they contain an `__init__.py` or not.

Comment: I think I was doing my non-relative imports wrong before, but now they work! `from models.user import User` correctly imports from `register_user.py`.

Answer (score 0):

The way I approached this was using [the GAE 3rd party lib vendoring technique](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27#installing_a_library):

- created `appengine_config.py`:

content:

```
from google.appengine.ext import vendor

# Add any libraries installed in the "lib" folder.
vendor.add('lib')
```

- created the `/app/lib` dir
- added an empty `__init__.py` file in the `models` dir to make it a package
- placed/moved/symlinked the `models` dir inside the `/app/lib` dir

With this the models can be referenced using:

```
from models.user import User
```

Possibly of interest:

- [Define common files for GAE projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38421955/define-common-files-for-gae-projects)
- [How do I access a vendored library from a module in Python Google App Engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34973058/how-do-i-access-a-vendored-library-from-a-module-in-python-google-app-engine)

Comment: Vendoring is for third-party code, there should be no need to use the vendor extension for your own code (and in fact doing so violates the conventions of it in the first place).

Comment: @BillPrin I admit, I found it convenient and just went for it. What do you mean by "violates the conventions" - violation of some Google policy or just violation of some convention?