# python google app engine stripe integration

Tags: python, google-app-engine, stripe-payments

I am working on a project in which i want to integrate stripe for payments. I am following their documentation to integrate it in python [Stripe Documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/charges). In documentation they downloaded the stripe library to use it. The code to download it was:

```
pip install --upgrade stripe
```

I followed the same steps. But i am getting this error. When i try to import it in my project.

```
import stripe
ImportError: No module named stripe
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proper way to install a 3rd party library into your GAE application is described in [Installing a library](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27?hl=en#installing_a_library):

> The easiest way to manage this is with a ./lib directory:
>
> 1. Use pip to install the library and the vendor module to enable importing packages from the third-party library directory.
> 2. Create a directory named lib in your application root directory:
>
>    ```
>    mkdir lib
>    ```
> 3. To tell your app how to find libraries in this directory, create or modify a file named appengine_config.py in the root of your
>      project, then add these lines:
>
>    ```
>    from google.appengine.ext import vendor
>
>    # Add any libraries installed in the "lib" folder.
>    vendor.add('lib')
>    ```
> 4. Use pip with the -t lib flag to install libraries in this directory:
>
>    ```
>    pip install -t lib gcloud
>    ```

**Notes**:

- When going through the mentioned doc page pay attention as it also contains instructions for requesting and using GAE-provided *built-in* libraries - different than those for *installed/vendored-in* libraries.
- if your app is a multi-module one you'll need an `appengine_config.py` for each module using the library at step#3, located beside the module's `.yaml` file. It can be symlinked for DRY reasons if you prefer (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/34291789/4495081).
- step #4's goal is to just bring the content of the stripe library in a subdirectory of the `lib` dir. You can do that manually if the pip way fails for whatever reason.

Comment: I followed the steps. At 4th step it said "Collecting strip
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement strip (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for strip"

Comment: But i manually put the library in lib directory now how can i implicitly import it in my app.

Comment: step 4's goal is to just bring the content of the stripe library in a subdirectory of the `lib` dir. You can do that manually if the `pip` way failed.

Comment: with the `appengine_config.py` in place your import should just work. You may need to restart your local devserver, tho.

Comment: There is a file named "appcfg.py". There is no file in directory named "appengine_config.py"

Comment: is your app a multi-service/module one?

Comment: Let me try it again.

Comment: Thank you So much for your help :) Keep on doing this good deed.

Answer (score 0):

When you pip installed stripe, it installed it in your local system.  But GAE does not have that package, so you cannot simply import it in production.  You need to download the package, and add it inside your app.  For example, in a "libs" directory.  Then, it will upload with the rest of your app when you deploy, and be available to the app.  Then, you import it like this:

```
from libs import stripe
```

Assuming your app structure looks like this:

```
- myapp
  - app.yaml
  - otherstuff.py
  - libs
    - stripe
```

Comment: from libs import stripe
ImportError: No module named libs

Comment: Try putting stripe in the same directory as the rest of your app, then just `import stripe`.  If that works, then you know your libs directory is not set up properly.  It should have an `__init.py__` and be in the sys path.