# Is there a way to access the Google Cloud metadata service from AppEngine Standard for runtime configuration?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I would like to access the [Metadata Service](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/storing-retrieving-metadata) from a App Engine Standard application.  I tried doing a urlfetch to `http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/project/attributes` and got back `DNS lookup failed`:

```
    logging.info(urlfetch.fetch('http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/project/attributes/').content)
```

Is this possible?  I'd like to share config between App Engine Flex and Standard code in the same project.

Comment: Show us the code you used

Comment: edited to add code above

Comment: Which language is this? Python?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Some friendly folks on the [GCP slack channel](https://gcp-slack.appspot.com/) pointed me to the  [RuntimeConfig API](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/runtime-configurator/create-and-delete-runtimeconfig-resources) for sharing configuration across multiple types of services in Google Cloud.  This solves the problem of sharing configs that I was looking for.

For those curious you have to:

1. [Enable the API in API Manager](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/runtimeconfig.googleapis.com/overview) for your google cloud project
2. Run some `gcloud` commands:

   ````
   gcloud beta deployment-manager runtime-configs create foo-credentials
   gcloud beta deployment-manager runtime-configs variables set "bar-variable-name" "baz-value"  --config-name "foo-credentials"```
   ````
3. Add the python `google-cloud-runtimeconfig` library to your project (I did it via `pip`)
4. Add some python code to fetch the variable at runtime:

   ````
   config_client = runtimeconfig.Client()
   config = config_client.config('foo-credentials')
   bar = config.get_variable('bar-variable-name')```
   ````

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't access the (GCE-specific) metadata from a GAE standard instance since it's not a GCE VM/instance. From [Getting metadata](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/storing-retrieving-metadata#querying) (emphasis mine):

> You can query the contents of the metadata server by making a request
>   to the following root URLs **from within a virtual machine instance**.
>   Use the `http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/` URL to
>   make requests to the metadata server.

The DNS failure you see for `metadata.google.internal` is a likely indicator that it's a special host DNS entry available only inside the GCE network or machine.

But in general it is possible to share files across GAE services/modules by symlinking the same file (ideally placed in the app dir) inside each of the service/module dir requiring it. See examples here: [Sharing entities between App Engine modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34291075/sharing-entities-between-app-engine-modules/34291789#34291789) and here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34111170/4495081

As long as the flex service/module uses the same file(s) content(s) the same way as the standard one does, this technique should work for them as well, meaning you can share configs by sharing an `appengine_config.py` file, for example.

Comment: thanks @Dan, that's my suspicion too --  I don't think the symlink trick between services (although cool) would work between App Engine flex and App Engine standard?

Comment: I didn't yet play with flex env, so I can't tell with certainty. But maybe it's worth a try?

Comment: the thing @Dan is I have several independent services which are not from one common code base, but I want them to be able to share metadata for configuration.  Having symlinks between them doesn't make sense because they aren't even aware of each other in some cases

Comment: @jcjones1515: I mentioned the symlinks solely thinking about having the relevant configs in sync across modules (duplicating info is error prone). Of course that has to be sanity-checked in your actual project context.