# Get compute metadata from app engine, got 404 page not found error

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I try to get project-wide `metadata` from app engine, the url like this:

`http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/project/attributes/IT_EBOOKS_API`

The `stackdriver logging` give me an error:

`message: '404 - "404 page not found\\n"',`

But I can get `metadata` from compute engine. Here is the `metadata` output:

```
novaline_dulin@test:~$ curl http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/project/attributes/IT_EBOOKS_API -H 
"Metadata-Flavor: Google"
http://it-ebooks-api.info/v1novaline_dulin@test:~$
```

And, here is my code for getting custom project-wide `metadata`

```js
const request = require('request-promise');

async function getMetaData(attr) {
  const url = `http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/project/attributes/${attr}`;
  const options = {
    headers: {
      'Metadata-Flavor': 'Google'
    }
  };
  console.log('url:', url);
  return request(url, options)
    .then((response) => {
      console.info(`Retrieve meta data successfully. meta data: ${response}`);
      return response;
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error('Retrieve meta data failed.', err);
      return '';
    });
}
```

Is there something wrong?  thanks.

**update**

I can get `project-id` from `metadata` server correctly. Here is the code:

```js
const METADATA_PROJECT_ID_URL = 'http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/project/project-id';

async function getProjectId() {
  const options = {
    headers: {
      'Metadata-Flavor': 'Google'
    }
  };

  return request(METADATA_PROJECT_ID_URL, options)
    .then((response) => {
      console.log('response: ', response);
      return response;
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      if (err && err.statusCode !== 200) {
        console.log('Error while talking to metadata server.');
        return 'Unknown_Project_ID';
      }
      return Promise.reject(err);
    });
}
```

Comment: which GAE environment?

Comment: @DanCornilescu standard environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the reason, it's metadata api **version** issue.

Instead of using

`http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1beta/project/attributes/${attr}`

use

`http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/project/attributes/${attr}`

Now, I can get `metadata` from app engine flexible environment.

```
{"IT_EBOOKS_API":"http://it-ebooks-api.info/v1","PROJECT_ID":"just-aloe-212502","API_KEY":"12j28flsrbapznq"}
```

But for `GAE` standard environment and `GCF`.  Still get `404 page not found`

So I think but not sure that `GCF` and `GAE` standard environment are not running in compute engine.

`GAE` flexiable environment use compute engine as its infrastructure. That's why it can get metadata from compute engine.

Answer (score 1):

A while ago this wasn't at all possible in the standard environment, see [Is there a way to access the Google Cloud metadata service from AppEngine Standard for runtime configuration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41005395/is-there-a-way-to-access-the-google-cloud-metadata-service-from-appengine-standa/41019436#41019436)

But things appear to be changing.

There is a [mentioning](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/accessing-instance-metadata) of the Metadata service in the (1st generation) standard environment documentation, **but**:

- only for the `java` sandbox
- *potentially* limited scope - only a subset of the endpoints mentioned, maybe the user-configured aren't, indeed, covered. But may be a matter of interpretation (emphasis mine):

> The following table lists **the** endpoints where you can make HTTP
>   requests for specific metadata.

- read-only:

> **Note**: Metadata access is currently read only: you cannot write your own metadata for an instance.

This means the DNS limitation making it impossible a while ago was eliminated. Since you can get the data in the flexible environment it means it exists and you're not really trying to write it, so  what you experience isn't related to the read-only limitation either.

It seems that indeed the service feature/endpoint you seek is more likely not available/functional, at least for the `go` sandbox (if not for all of them), rather than just an accidental documentation omission (which one might suspect/hope).

Comment: But the `metadata` can be retrieved in `GAE` flexible environment. I am pretty sure of this. What a `GCP`, waste my a lot of times.

Comment: Yes, it's actually part of the recommended alternative for the [missing App identity](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/migrating#app_identity). But that's a different environment. And I'm not certain the custom endpoints work in that case either.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error using python APIs from a compute engine VM.  Refreshing the key file and using the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable to point to it explicitly seemed to work.  Even when that account was the only account configured with `gcloud auth`, I still had the error.  I'm probably missing something in my understanding of where the Python libraries get their credentials from, but at least I have a workaround for the moment.