# Communicating between google app engine services

Tags: python, google-app-engine

My project structure looks like below,

```
.
├── app
│   ├── api
│   ├── models
│   ├── services
│   │   └── lib
|   |   |__ worker.yaml
|   |   |__ worker.py
|   |_ main.py
|_ app.yaml
```

I'm trying to import `models` from `app` module (ie, default module) in `worker.py` like,

```
from app.models import db
```

But it shows `No module named app.models`. But I can achieve the same inside `main.py`.Note that I'm running both `app.yaml` and `worker.yaml` files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When deployed, GAE Services/modules do not share **anything** outside their module directory, which is the directory in which their `.yaml` file exists.

So `worker.py` won't see anything above the `services` dir (where `worker.yaml` exists), thus it can't see `models`. But `main.py` can, since models is inside its `app` dir (where `app.yaml` exists).

You could symlink `models` inside `services` if you want, see [Sharing entities between App Engine modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34291075/sharing-entities-between-app-engine-modules/34291789?s=1|1.7248#34291789)

Or maybe take a look at [Can a default service/module in a Google App Engine app be a sibling of a non-default one in terms of folder structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34110178/can-a-default-module-in-a-google-app-engine-app-be-a-sibling-of-a-non-default-mo/34111170#34111170) for an example of how I'd structure a multi-module app?

Comment: so creating symbolic link for worker.yaml inside the project's root directory will work, right? I tried so, but still I can't make it to work.

Comment: Not the same thing: you'd have 2 worker.yaml files in 2 different locations. Ambiguous wrt determining the module's top dir.

Comment: Why do you structure your services inconsistently (one in the `.` dir and one in the `./app/services` dir?

Comment: does symlinking works when we deploy our app through gcloud?

Comment: symlinking works locally , just to know whether it would work on deployment through gcloud.

Comment: Yes, it works, the deployment utility replaces the symlink with the actual content. The diffference between local and GAE is visibility outside/above the module dir - visible locally, but not when deployed.

Comment: I'm using the same structure with creating symbolic links for app folder. It works.

Comment: Now I got another problem "ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [400] This deployment has too many files. New versions are limited to 10000 files for this app"

Comment: One of my symlinked file path shows `/home/avinash/up_project/s2s_backend/app/services/app/services/app/services/app/services/app/services/app/services/app/services/app/services/app/services/app/services/app/services/app/services/app/services/app/services/app/services/app/services/app/services/app/services/app/services/app/services/app/services/app/services/app/services/app/services/app/services/app/services/app/services/app/services/app/services/app/services/app/services/app/services/app/services/app/services/app/services/app/services/lib/werkzeug`

Comment: Re-check your symlinks for circular references.