# How to integrate Python and Java together for an app in Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

Is it possible to make an application which uses two programming language such as java and python together? I mean if there are two services which one of them is in Java and another in Python, what is the simplest way to integrate them ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, you can use two programming languages in an GAE app using [GAE services.](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/microservices-on-app-engine)

If you want the services to communicate then it would be possible through http requests, task queues. If you want a folder to be available in both the services then create that folder on the project's root directory and do sym-linking inside necessary services.

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42425048/3297613)

Comment: Thank you, I would like to know if you have a sample project which uses GAR services having two languages in an GAE app.