# How to package python3 modules for google app engine

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine-python

I'm trying to figure out how to add a internal package to a Google App Engine deployment with Python 3 (standard).

For Python 2 the way to package modules was using a local `lib/` folder and [`appengine_config.py`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27). This seems not to work anymore for Python 3? At least my app cannot find modules which are in the `lib/` folder.

For Python 3 it's possible to just `pip3 install -t .` the package. But this gets really messy as all packages are just installed in the app root and will also be added to the git repository of our app.

We cannot use `requirements.txt` as the module is internal and will not be available on PyPI.

Is there another way to package modules for Google App Engine using Python 3?

Comment: Try placing the package's directory right under the top level service directory rather than under `lib`, side-by-side with with the `app.yaml` file. From GAE's perspective this *should* appear just like another package of your app code. Not sure if just symlinking the directory from somewhere else would work like in the 1st generation (python 2.7) standard environment (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/34291789/4495081) to avoid copying the package

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Python 3.7 Standard runtime is an "idiomatic" Python runtime, which means it doesn't automatically add the special `lib` directory to the search path for modules.

You should continue "vendoring" your private modules into a `lib` directory, but you'll need to make a change to how you import them.

If your private package is `foobar`, and you've done `pip install -t lib foobar`, then in your project, instead of:

```
import foobar
```

you do:

```
import lib.foobar
```

(You'll also need to add an empty `__init__.py` file to your `lib` directory, to make it a module.)