# Multiple Services in Google App Engine Python 3.7

Tags: google-app-engine, python-3.7, app.yaml

I have an application that ran fine under the Python 2.7 Standard framework, and runs fine as two separate applications in the 3.7 framework, but I can't figure out how to configure them as a single application with two services.
main.app consists of the following two lines (paralleling what used to work in the 2.7 framework)

```
from app import app
from update import update
```

The app.yaml for main consists of nothing but runtime: python37

Each of the two python packages under main (app and update) have their own app.yaml as the new deployment document says they are supposed to.  The problem is in the **update** package.  I used to specify a handler which had script: main.update.  That is no longer allowed (only auto is allowed.)  Note that the **app** package works fine because app is the default entrypoint. I gather that the new way to specify where to go when the update service is run is to use entrypoint, but even after adding gunicorn to the requirements, the yaml statement

```
entrypoint: gunicorn b :$PORT main::update
```

which seems to be what's required, simply gives me a 500 http return.  I also tried variants like main.update to no avail.

```
main.py  
app.yaml  
-->/app
-----> /app/__init__.py  
-----> /app/app.yaml  
-->/update  
------> /update/__init__.py  
------> /update/app.yaml
```

There are also template subdirectories to both packages and some other stuff, but they all work fine when run as separate **versions**

Here is my attempted yaml in the update directory:

```
runtime: python37

service: update

entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT main.update
```

And here is the yaml in the app directory, which seems to work fine:

```
runtime: python37

service: default

handlers:
- url: /static
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.(bmp|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|png))

automatic_scaling:
  max_idle_instances: 2
  max_concurrent_requests: 12
```

Comment: Show your app dir structure, the 2 .yaml files and the 2 python files containing the server apps (matching the configured entry points, if any). Maybe peek at https://stackoverflow.com/a/34111170/4495081 (1st gen, though, but that shouldn't be such an issue).

Comment: I looked at that, and that was the way I used to have it, but the new docs [here] (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/configuration-files) say that won't work.  But I'll edit above

Comment: I don't see where the doc says that. And I don't see how what you did comes resembles to what's in the doc...

Comment: Are you trying to split a single-service app in a 2 service app in the same time with migrating from 2.7 to 3.7? Show also the `before` versions of the `.yaml` file(s) that were working.

Comment: In the 2.7 world, I just had all of the service .yaml files in the root directory. Each one had a different script line (under url: /.*) that told the entrypoint of the service. (main.app and main.update).  Then I just strung out all the .yaml files in one deploy statement and everything just worked.  I may try to fix everything in the way you suggest, but for now I've just crammed all of it into the default service, and it works fine, but I only have one service.  That's not too big a deal because I can just use cron.yaml to run the update service by itself by naming an entry route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at what you described and assuming you are aiming for a directory structure similar to the one mentioned in the [Example](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/configuration-files#examples) section of the doc you referenced I see a few problems.

You still have code in the app's top/root directory, above the services' directories - the `main.py` and `app.yaml` files - such code isn't accessible to the services. The `app.yaml` file in particular may actually cause problems as it *might* accidentally be interpreted as the `.yaml` file of a single-service app. I'd get rid of these files.

I would only keep in the app's top-level dir [app-level optional config files](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/configuration-files#optional_configuration_files) and, if applicable, files intended to contain code shared by multiple services, which I would symlink inside each of the services sharing the code, see [Sharing entities between App Engine modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34291075/sharing-entities-between-app-engine-modules/34291789#34291789)

In the `update/app.yaml` file you're using the wrong syntax for the entrypoint configuration:

- you should have **a single** `:` delimiter between the module name and the WSGI app variable name, i.e `main:update`, not `main::update` or `main.update`. This assumes you have an `update/main.py` file defining your WSGI-compatible application called `update` (if the application is called `app` instead then you'd use `main:app`)
- in one example you have `b` instead of `-b`

You don't have an entrypoint defined in the `app/app.yaml` file. Most likely your `default` service meets the conditions in which a default entrypoint is automatically added, see [Application startup](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/runtime#application_startup):

> - The root of your app directory contains a `main.py` file with a WSGI-compatible object called `app`.
> - `app.yaml` does not contain the entrypoint field.
> - Your app does not contain `Pipfile` or `Pipfile.lock` files.

Personally I prefer to not rely on this default behaviour, I'd explicitly add the entry point:

```
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app
```